# "channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed" when creating a VNC session on a SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, vnc, port-forwarding

On creating a VNC connection via tunneled SSH connection, I get an error:

```
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

I have found that this happens only when I'm not logged into the host locally as the `username` on the host I'm trying to connect to using a tunneled VNC connection. SSH Tunnel:

```
ssh -p 6000 -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 username@192.168.0.2
```

VNC connection:

```
vncviewer localhost:1
```

I've tried adjusting the settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` using `AllowTunnel yes` and without the setting. (I did restart ssh after each change: `service ssh restart`) However, the error goes away if I have a local session running on the remote host (i.e. I'm logged in as `username` locally.) Is anyone else seeing this behavior? It seems like I should be able to start a VNC remotely and access it with out having to logged in locally as well.

Comment: Mike, please check the [tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how does this site work and if my answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 19):

The option you are looking for is not `AllowTunnel` (it is for VPN and level 3 forwarding using `tun` devices). You are looking for `AllowTcpForwarding`, which handles local and remote port forwarding of TCP traffic in ssh.

Have a look what values is in your server and change it to `yes`:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. That seems to have fixed my issue. I had seen others with the same issue and one suggestion was `AllowTunnel yes` in `sshd_config`, but that did not work for me.

Comment: It is probably some urban legend, as also the other answer came here. No idea where did it come from and it is so easy to open manual page and check the meaning. If it works for you, have a second to check the answer as solution to help others.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: `AllowTcpForwarding`
    
             Specifies whether TCP forwarding is permitted.  The available options are “yes” or “all” to allow
             TCP forwarding, “no” to prevent all TCP forwarding, “local” to allow local (from the perspective of
             ssh(1)) forwarding only or “remote” to allow remote forwarding only.  **The default is “yes”.**

Comment: related (false): https://serverfault.com/a/24389/328011

Answer (score 0):

I had a name resolution cause for this error. My /etc/hosts had an erroneous IP address for the name of the server (not for localhost), like this:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
192.168.2.45  server.domain.com server
```

But the configured server IP (and the DNS name resolved with the host/dig commands) was 192.168.2.47. A simple typo caused by a previous IP reconfiguration. After fixing /etc/hosts the tunnel connection worked flawlessly:

```
ssh user@server.domain.com -L 3456:127.0.0.1:5901
```

It is weird that the real IP caused the failure when I was using the localhost literal IP for the tunnel. Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.